# How to use mod rewrite on specific urls not patterns

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite the url www.example.com/shows?lang=en to www.example.com/shows/index.php?lang=en,

but everything else in the folder eg www.example.com/shows/jamie?lang=en to www.example.com/shows/jamie.php?lang=en

I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^shows shows/index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

but the first line rewrites www.example.com/shows/jamie?lang=en to www.example.com/shows/index.php?lang=en

Is there a way to make the first line only work on the specific url and not other urls in the folder?

Comment: RewriteRule ^shows/?$